# Python Pygame codes running very slow when imported from another file

Tags: python, pygame

I'm relatively new to python so forgive me if the answer is so obvious.

```
def create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, aliens):
    """Create the horizontal Alien fleet"""
    alien = Alien(ai_settings, screen)
    alien_width = alien.rect.width
    available_x = ai_settings.screen_width - alien_width
    num_aliens_x = int(available_x / ( 2 * alien_width))

    for alien_number_x in range(num_aliens_x):
        alien = Alien(ai_settings, screen)
        # define the starting point of each alien
        alien.x = alien_width + 2 * alien_width * alien_number_x
        alien.rect.x = alien.x
        aliens.add(alien)

def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets, aliens):
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_colour)
    ship.blitme()
    for bullet in bullets.sprites():
        bullet.draw_bullet()
    aliens.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

This is the main game file:

def run_game():

```
ai_settings = Settings()


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("ALIEN INVASION")
bullets = Group()
aliens = Group()



ship = Ship(screen, ai_settings)
while True:
    gf.check_event(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
    ship.update()
    bullets.update()
    gf.remove_old_bullets(bullets) 

    **gf.create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, aliens)
    gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets, aliens)**
```

run_game()

Whenever I import these functions into the main game file and I run the game it crawls but when the codes are run directly on the main game file it runs normally. Please, suggestions on how to make it work properly when imported.

Edited: I've added the main game file, the bolded is where I used the imported code that is giving me problems. Thanks

Comment: Could you add your main script so the problem is reproducable for us?

Comment: Thanks. I just did.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to solve it. The function gf.create_fleet shouldn't be in the while loop as it will continuously be adding to the group at same location and the gf update_screen had to draw all of it at same point which was a serious issue and made my programming crawl